# Run sh file when Amazon EC2 instance starts

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, node.js

I have a "sh" file that starts a node server.

It works well if I run

```
sh /var/www/init_node.sh
```

I want the script to run everytime my instance restarts (so I have a node server up and running).

I added the script to my /etc/rc.local file as follows:

```
sh /var/www/init_node.sh 
exit 0
```

However, when I restart the instance, the nodejs server is not running.  It's a Ubuntu 64 instance.

I think that it's not important, but here is the content of my sh file:

```
cd /var/www/myproject
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
git stash
git pull origin master --force
forever start express.js
```

Also

```
sh /etc/rc.local
```

works fine

Any ideas?

Comment: It will be worthwhile capturing the output from the script, either from the standard log files (I'm not sure which one) or by redirecting STDOUT and STDERR to a new file.  The error message will probably tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the rc.local file on an amazon instance. It turned out for me that I had an error with the script in rc.local that would not allow it to execute unless I had a tty.

So how do you find out if your getting a similar error? Use cloud-init to execute your script.

For my amazon linux distro I first edited `/etc/init.d/cloud-init-user-scripts`.

Change this line 
`/usr/bin/cloud-init-run-module once-per-instance user-scripts execute run-parts ${SCRIPT_DIR} >/dev/null && success || failure`

TO "always"

`/usr/bin/cloud-init-run-module always user-scripts execute run-parts ${SCRIPT_DIR} >/dev/null && success || failure`

Then create a directory `mkdir /var/lib/cloud/data/scripts` .. Now copy your script that you wish to have executed on startup to `/var/lib/cloud/data/scripts`. Make sure your scripts executable bit is set.

Now you should be able to execute `sudo /etc/init.d/cloud-init-user-scripts start` .. Then you can check `/var/log/cloud-init.log` for errors.